# Want button to be visible after being invisible

Tags: android, visibility, countdowntimer

I have a problem with a button to be invisible when I want. In my if statement I have declared the exerciseButtonDone to first to be invisible but then after the final countdown I want it to become visible.

As my code is right now the button is visible all the time.

```
package org.example.anders.eazy;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ExerciseActivity extends Activity {

    String[] exerciseList;
    TextView textTimer,workoutTextview,exerciseTextView;
    int setsChosen;
    int counter = 0;
    int timeChosen;
    boolean togglebuttonpress;
    Button exerciseButtonDone;
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        exerciseList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.heavy_chest_arms);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercise);
        exerciseButtonDone=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonActiveExcercise);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String selectedWorkout = intent.getExtras().getString("workoutName");
        togglebuttonpress=intent.getExtras().getBoolean("togglebuttonPress");

        textTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeUntilFinished);
        //workoutTextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.workoutChosen);
        //workoutTextview.setText(selectedWorkout);
        if(togglebuttonpress){
            exerciseButtonDone.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            setsChosen =intent.getExtras().getInt("setsChosen");
            int timePass = intent.getExtras().getInt("timeChosen");
            timeChosen=timePass;
            counter = 0;
            runCountDownTimer();
            exerciseButtonDone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        else {

            textTimer.setText("");
            exerciseButtonDone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


        //exerciseTextView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exerciseNow);
        //exerciseTextView.setText(exerciseList[i]);

    }

    public void runCountDownTimer() {

        if (counter < setsChosen) {
            new CountDownTimer(timeChosen * 60000, 1000) {

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    long millis = millisUntilFinished;
                    String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d",
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
                    System.out.println(hms);
                    textTimer.setText(hms);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    counter++;
                    v.vibrate(500);
                    runCountDownTimer();
                }
            }.start();
        }
        textTimer.setText("Complete");

    }
}
```

Comment: What does the toggleButtonPress variable represent again?

Comment: It's a passed boolean from previous activty.

Comment: The exerciseButtonDone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); should be on the else of the if (counter < setsChosen) or in the onFinish method, but since you restart your countdown on the onfinish maybe better on the "else"

Comment: Your countdowntimer seems to re-run itself ad-nauseam.  Is that intended?  You also set the `textTimer` at a weird place.  I don't think it'll ever say complete.  That should probably be moved to the same `onFinish` method.

Comment: It's intended. The countdowntimer run the number of times until it has the same value as setsChosen.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the button invisible and then immediately visible.

```
    if(togglebuttonpress){
        exerciseButtonDone.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        ...
        exerciseButtonDone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

move `exerciseButtonDone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` from its current location to where the countdown timer actually finishes, which I now see is `runCountDownTimer()`

```
if (counter < setsChosen) {
    new CountDownTimer(timeChosen * 60000, 1000) {
        ...
    }
} else {
    exerciseButtonDone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

you'll still need to make `execerciseButtonDone` `final`... and move it to the right scope, thank you alex.  It needs to be a class variable, over by say `boolean togglebuttonpress;`

you COULD do `findViewById` again, but that's redundant and unnecessary.

Comment: When i do it I get message when hoovering over exerciseButtonDone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); that Cannot resolve symbol 'exerciseButtonDone'

Comment: Because you delcared your button in the onCreate method.... Basic java.... I strongly suggest to start to study some Java before getting into android programming.

Comment: The problem if I place exerciseButtonDone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); under runCountDownTimer(); is that I don´t want to show the button until the countdown stops looping. After the first loop the button comes and a new countdown starts.

Comment: I see what you want now, it wasn't clear to me what you were doing.  So, looks like after the final iteration of the countdown timer, `runCountDownTimer()` will execute one last time and NOT start the timer again yes?  So how about there?  `if (counter < setsChosen) {...} else {/*make button visible*/}`?  You know what, I'll just edit for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I added an if statement that checked if loop was done. It worked.

```
public void onFinish() {
                    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    counter++;
                    v.vibrate(500);
                    runCountDownTimer();
                    if (counter == setsChosen)
                    {
                        exerciseButtonDone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
```